# How to solve the following question?

Tags: inequality

If $x$, $y$ are positive real numbers such that $3x+4y<72$, then the maximum possible value of $12xy(72-3x-4y)=?$

a) $12240$

b) $13824$

c) $10656$

d) $8640$

I am trying this question by drawing the graph of the equation 3x+4y=72 and then enclosing the region 3x+4y<72. But how to proceed further because from the graph the maximum value is unknown.

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange! Please note that this site is not designed to give you direct solutions to math problems. Instead, it is to assist you with any conceptual problems you face while solving a problem or understanding a math topic. To receive the most out of this community, it is essential to include the approach you took to solve the problem yourself or mention any specific challenges you faced while solving the problem.

Comment: I am trying this question by drawing the graph of 3x+4y=72. And enclosing the region where 3x+4y<72. But how to proceed after that?

Comment: From the graph I think it is not possible to find the maximum value of 12xy(72-3x-4y)

Comment: You can click on the 'edit' button right below your question, to add these details to the body of your question. Anyone having the relevant knowledge then will try to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AM-GM for three positive numbers,
$$(3x)(4y)(72-3x-4y)\leqslant \left(\frac{3x+4y+(72-3x-4y)}{3} \right)^3$$

This can be an equality when $3x=4y=72-3x-4y\implies(x, y) = (8, 6)$, which is allowed by the constraint, hence this gives you the maximum.

Comment: Thank you very much